# Show that $f(x)=x^3+x$ is continuous at $x=2$

Tags: calculus

It's possible to show that for $f(x)=x^3+x$,

$|f(x)-f(2)| \le 20|x-2|$ for $0 \le x \le 3$

Then I've chose $\delta = min\left\lbrace 1,\frac{\epsilon}{20} \right\rbrace$, because

$|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{20} \implies 20|x-2|<\epsilon \implies |f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$

Then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=2$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: But, if $\epsilon=1$ then $\delta=\frac1{20}$, right ?

Comment: I'm stupid yes, it works but your bound seems arbitrary, to make your proof complete you should explain the last implication, but it should work

Comment: Looks right. As a proof you may have to explain more why "$|f(x)-f(2)| \le 20|x-2|$ for $0 \le x \le 3$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove $x^3+x$ is continuous at $x=2$

---

$2-\delta < x < 2+\delta$

$8-12\delta+6\delta^2-\delta^3<x^3<8+12\delta+6\delta^2+\delta^3$

$10-13\delta+6\delta^2-\delta^3<x^3+x<10+13\delta+6\delta^2+\delta^3$

The absolute value of the alternating delta expression on the left is smaller than the absolute value of the uniform plus sign expression on the right, so we seek to establish an upperbound for it.

Let $0<\delta <1$

$\delta = \min (1, \epsilon/20)$

$-13\delta+6\delta^2-\delta^3<x^3+x-10<13\delta+6\delta^2+\delta^3<20\delta<\epsilon$

So choose $\delta$ so
$0<\delta<\min(1, \epsilon/20)$

---

Alternative

$-\epsilon < x^3+x-10<\epsilon$

$-\epsilon < (x-2)(x^2+2x+5)<\epsilon$

$\frac{-\epsilon}{(x+1)^2+4}<x-2<\frac{\epsilon}{(x+1)^2+4}$

$\frac{-\epsilon}{(x-2)^2+6(x-2)+13}<x-2<\frac{\epsilon}{(x-2)^2+6(x-2)+13}$

And we again let $\delta = \min (1,\epsilon/20)$.